# Migration urls in app ...has no Migration class

Tags: django, django-migrations

When I try to run migration I get  `"Migration urls in app *** has no Migration class"`? I just added new app.

Have no idea what direction to look. Traceback:

```
C:\Users\PAPA\DEV\liberty\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\__init__.py:55:
RemovedInDjango19Warning: The utilities in django.db.models.loading are deprecated 
in favor of the new application loading system.
from . import loading

Traceback (most recent call last):   File "manage.py", line 22, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
File "...\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 338, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
File "...\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 330, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
File "...\django\core\management\base.py", line 390, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
File "...\django\core\management\base.py", line 441, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
File "...\django\core\management\commands\makemigrations.py", line 63, in handle
    loader = MigrationLoader(None, ignore_no_migrations=True)
File "...\django\db\migrations\loader.py", line 47, in __init__
    self.build_graph()
File "...\django\db\migrations\loader.py", line 174, in build_graph
    self.load_disk()
File "...\django\db\migrations\loader.py", line 109, in load_disk
    "Migration %s in app %s has no Migration class" % (migration_name, app_config.label)
django.db.migrations.loader.BadMigrationError: Migration urls in app expense has no
Migration class
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

That exception
    `BadMigrationError: "Migration *** in app *** has no Migration class"`
is raised if the `"migrations/"` directory of the application contains a file that **is not a valid migration file**.

In your case it is a file "urls.py" in migrations of the application "expense".